# Office JS SSO getuserdata method not working when deployed

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, office-js

I have an Office Excel Javascript addin, create by using yeoman office generator, with sso options. During development, I did the configure-sso and it created all of the Azure apps and while using it locally, it worked, and could pull my graph data.

Now I have deployed it on Azure, updated the manifest (exchanged localhost to app.azurewebsites.net, added graph.microsoft.com in appdomains just in case), updated the urls in app, updated the app registration with callback url to also new domain.

But when calling now get user token, it doesn't work, with error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Upon deeper digging, it crashes when calling app.azurewebsites.net/getuserdata?_=... Weirdly, I have no idea where does this method come from (searching only finds the call in the mapped .js file), but on localhost...getuserdata it works and gives me back my data and the code runs ok, but on azure no.

I deployed this by uploading the dist folder to the azure web service (after npm run build), and the rest of the add-in functionality works, except the graph communication.

does anyone know what did i miss, I'm assuming this is some configuration issue.

Comment: `getuserdata` is in the \node_modules\office-addin-sso\src\app.ts file. It is called by the `makeGraphApiCall` function in the file msgraph-helper.ts in the same folder. I think the problem has to do with the fact that the Yo Office generated project depends on an .ENV file in the project root. But I don't think this file is duplicated on app.azurewebsites.net site. I'll see if I can get some help internally at Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you
Yeah, the .env is not in the dist folder, i also assumed if i have to check something there, but the only url there is /me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project created by the SSO option in the yeoman office generator, as presently architected, cannot be ported from localhost to a real website. We are working on a new version that overcomes this.

In the meantime, a project created this way cannot be used as the starter project for a production add-in that uses SSO. Instead, you should use the "Complete" version of one of the "SSO" samples in this folder: [Office Add-ins Samples - auth](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/auth)